# How to: Member notification after Channel Form submission

Tags: members, ee3, notification

I have a Channel Form in which the user chooses a member from a different member group and when they submit the form, that member receives a notification. Is it possible to do this with any existing add-on (or out of the box)?

It sounds like MX Notify would be perfect for this, but it's not compatible with EE3.